# How work object variable in php (oop)?

Tags: php, algorithm, function, oop, logic

I have class which is using for factory pattery. It is working properly, but issue is that i'm unable to understand how object variable work. Please see below example i hope you will more clear what i want to say.

### Class (Working Properly)

```
class VehicleStore{
         public function __construct() {
            $this->VehicleFactory = new VehicleFactory();
         } 

         public function buyCar($vehicleName){

            $this->VehicleFactory->create($vehicleName);
        }

    }
```

### Want Understand How it Work

I want to understand how this object work in specific patter.

```
$this->VehicleFactory = new VehicleFactory();
```

When i change it to simple variable then its not working.

```
$VehicleFactory = new VehicleFactory();
```

Can anyone guide me, many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Learn the [basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php). With `$this->property` you are accessing a class property, so you can access it from anther function/method.

Only with `$property` you just have a local variable in that method, so you can't access it in another method, if you don't pass it some how.